# Using Spark find completeness from multiple datasets

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have requirement to verify certain data present in multiple datasets(or csv) using Spark 2. This can is defined as matching of two more keys from all datasets and generate report of all matching and non matching keys from all datasets.
For e.g. There are four datasets and each dataset has two matching keys with other keys. It means all the datasets needs to be matched on two matching keys defined.Lets say  userId,userName are two matching keys in below datasets:

```
Dataset A: userId,userName,age,contactNumber
Dataset B: orderId,orderDetails,userId,userName
Dataset C: departmentId,userId,userName,departmentName
Dataset D: userId,userName,address,pin

Dataset A:    
userId,userName,age,contactNumber
1,James,29,1111
2,Ferry,32,2222
3,Lotus,21,3333

Dataset B:    
orderId,orderDetails,userId,userName
DF23,Chocholate,1,James
DF45,Gifts,3,Lotus

Dataset C:    
departmentId,userId,userName,departmentName
N99,1,James,DE
N100,2,Ferry,AI

Dataset D:    
userId,userName,address,pin
1,James,minland street,cvk-dfg
```

Need to generate a report (or similar report) like

```
------------------------------------------
userId,userName,status
------------------------------------------
1,James,MATCH
2,Ferry,MISSING IN B, MISSING IN D
3,Lotus,MISSING IN B, MISSING IN C, MISSING IN D
```

I have tried joining of datasets as follwos

```
DatsetA-B:
userId,userName,age,contactNumber,orderId,orderDetails,userId,userName,status
1,James,29,1111,DF23,Chocholate,1,James,MATCH
2,Ferry,32,2222,,,,,Missing IN Left
3,Lotus,21,3333,DF45,Gifts,3,Lotus,MATCH

DatsetC-D:
departmentId,userId,userName,departmentName,userId,userName,address,pin,status
N99,1,James,DE,1,James,minland street,cvk-dfg,MATCH
N100,2,Ferry,AI,,,,,Missing IN Right

DatsetAB-CD:
Joining criteria: userId and userName of A with C, userId and userName of B with D
userId,userName,age,contactNumber,orderId,orderDetails,userId,userName,status,departmentId,userId,userName,departmentName,userId,userName,address,pin,status,status
1,James,29,1111,DF23,Chocholate,1,James,MATCH,N99,1,James,DE,1,James,minland street,cvk-dfg,MATCH,MATCH
2,Ferry,32,2222,,,,,Missing IN Left,N100,2,Ferry,AI,,,,,Missing IN Right,Missing IN Right
```

No row is coming for userId 3

Comment: what have you tried so far? please share your tryings

Comment: I have tried combining two datasets A,B and C,D  and storing status between A,B and C,D. Now combining results of the two, but it is getting messy to handle.

Comment: can you update those in the question? and please mention the messy part as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data is defined as:

```scala
val dfA = Seq((1, "James", 29, 1111), (2, "Ferry", 32, 2222),(3, "Lotus", 21, 3333)).toDF("userId,userName,age,contactNumber".split(","): _*)
val dfB = Seq(("DF23", "Chocholate", 1, "James"), ("DF45", "Gifts", 3, "Lotus")).toDF("orderId,orderDetails,userId,userName".split(","): _*)
val dfC = Seq(("N99", 1, "James", "DE"), ("N100", 2, "Ferry", "AI")).toDF("departmentId,userId,userName,departmentName".split(","): _*)
val dfD = Seq((1, "James", "minland street", "cvk-dfg")).toDF("userId,userName,address,pin".split(","): _*)
```

Define keys:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val keys = Seq("userId", "userName")
```

Combine `Datasets`:

```scala
val dfs = Map("A" -> dfA, "B" -> dfB, "C" -> dfC, "D" -> dfD)

val combined = dfs.map {
  case (key, df) => df.withColumn("df", lit(key)).select("df", keys: _*) 
}.reduce(_ unionByName _)
```

Pivot and convert result to booleans:

```scala
val pivoted = combined
  .groupBy(keys.head, keys.tail: _*)
  .pivot("df", dfs.keys.toSeq)
  .count()

val result = dfs.keys.foldLeft(pivoted)(
  (df, c) => df.withColumn(c, col(c).isNotNull.alias(c))
)

// +------+--------+----+-----+-----+-----+
// |userId|userName|   A|    B|    C|    D|
// +------+--------+----+-----+-----+-----+
// |     1|   James|true| true| true| true|
// |     3|   Lotus|true| true|false|false|
// |     2|   Ferry|true|false| true|false|
// +------+--------+----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Use resulting boolean matrix to generate final report.

This can become pretty expensive when datasets become large. If you know that one dataset contains all possible keys, **and you don't require exact results** (some false negatives are acceptable), you can use Bloom filter.

Here we can use `dfA` as a reference:

```scala
val expectedNumItems = dfA.count
val fpp = 0.00001

val key = struct(keys map col: _*).cast("string").alias("key")

val filters = dfs.filterKeys(_ != "A").mapValues(df => { 
  val f = df.select(key).stat.bloomFilter("key", expectedNumItems, fpp); 
  udf((s: String) => f.mightContain(s))
 })

filters.foldLeft(dfA.select(keys map col: _*)){
  case (df, (c, f)) => df.withColumn(c, f(key))
}.show

// +------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
// |userId|userName|    B|    C|    D|
// +------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
// |     1|   James| true| true| true|
// |     2|   Ferry|false| true|false|
// |     3|   Lotus| true|false|false|
// +------+--------+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Bloom's Filter solution will not work as all datsets may be incomplete. But your first solution will work. We may compromise with performance.

Comment: `unionByName` is pretty much the same as `union` but matches column names instead of the order. You can safely use `union` here.